# Change the lock screen wallpaper in Kali Sana (Gnome)

Tags: kali-linux, screen-lock, wallpaper

I'm annoyed by the 'lock screen' wallpaper of KALI SANA 2.0. This is the default 'lock screen' wallpaper:

[image]

I have seen many tutorials on how to change the 'login screen' wallpaper/background but didn't find any about changing the 'lock screen' wallpaper/background picture.

Is there anyone that can guide me through the process of changing the 'lock screen' wallpaper in KALI Sana 2.0?

Comment: Does that use the Gnome desktop environment?

Comment: Go to _System Settings > Personal > Background_. You have to options there (and you can't miss them): _Background_ and _Lock Screen_.

Comment: Please check the comments on the answer below.

Comment: @don_crissti please check the comments on the answer below

Comment: Well, [per the docs](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/look-background.html.en) that's how you do it. Now, if you're using a distro that has the habit of customizing/patching/modifying upstream code I don't know what to advise.

Comment: @don_crissti I guess you cannot help me

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Make a file called `/usr/share/images/desktop-base/lockscreen.xml`, somewhat like this:

```
<background>
  <static>
    <duration>8640000.0</duration>
    <file>
      <size width="1920" height="1080">/path/to/wallpaper.jpg</size>
    </file>
  </static>
</background>
```

Then link the file like so: `ln -sfv /usr/share/images/desktop-base/lockscreen.xml /etc/alternatives/desktop-background.xml`

As root, run this: `/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` or just reboot. That should do it. That was the process in older versions of Gnome, so as long as it hasn't changed, you should be good to go.

Comment: I've just tried that out and it doesn't work.

Comment: @dryleaf, what version of Gnome does that have?

Comment: Gnome Shell 3.14.2

Comment: @dryleaf do you have a valid path pointing to your wallpaper? Maybe you could provide that file?

Comment: Yes, I do. The image is in a PNG format and the size is same as in the lockscreen.xml script.

Comment: Did you check the background menu? Looks like that has a lock screen option in that version of Gnome.

Comment: It doesn't work for lockscreen. It only opens a picture editor and only gives one option in the menu for set as wallpaper and this only changes the background of the desktop.

Comment: Do you have the dconf editor?

Comment: Yes I have the editor

Comment: You should find the setting in there.

Comment: It is not there

Comment: @dryleaf looks like it is set in the css, check out this script: http://fxin3.deviantart.com/art/UPDATED-GNOME-3-lockscreen-mod-478462065

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i'm afraid to say that that's about customizing the items on the gnome lockscreen, the file: gnome-shell.css itself doesn't contain any reference to change the background of the lockscreen.

Comment: But it does actually change the background, it seems that the background is actually rendered css. Strange I know, this is why I avoid Gnome.  ;^)

Comment: I scanned the .css file myself, I saw all the parameters block by block, the only thing the gnome-shell.css does is to customize the icons, lookAndFeel->robots, transparency, fonts and many more.

Comment: @dryleaf, aha! You need to put an image inside your `~/Pictures` directory and log into gdm as root. Then you will be able to set it in the right-click 'Change Background' setting.

Comment: I have not tried that. I will try and see.

Comment: The thing is that with Root account, it sets the desired image for the lockscreen but it doesn't reflect on the lockscreen itself. In other words, the default lockscreen doesn't change even when you have set the desired image for the lockscreen.

Comment: Did you restart gdm?

Comment: I did even better, I restarted my system.

Comment: I just tested that on the Kali live ISO and it worked for me ...

Comment: @dryleaf, did you try a JPG?

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with this for a little while, but what worked for me was annoyingly simple (and it also works for a custom desktop image):

- have your file in a file-explorer window ready to click on.
- right-click on the desktop and select **Change Desktop Background**
- select the lock-screen to customise (or the desktop) for a list of pictures available
- **drag** the image from the file-explorer window and **drop** it into to list of pictures shown in the last step (the cursor should change to have a small **+** visible
- the new picture appears in the list and can be selected

Answer (score 0):

As root:

 nano /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css

When the file opens:

 control w Type: lockDialogGroup Press: Enter

To find:

  #lockDialogGroup {

  background: #2c001e url(resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/noise-texture.png);

  background-repeat: repeat; }

Change the lines into:

  #lockDialogGroup {

  background: #2c001e url(file:///SOMEPATHTOSOMEFILE);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: cover;

  background-position: center; }

Restart and that should do it!

Comment: I appreciate you reaching out in 2018 but the distribution has changed a lot since 2015 and lots of bugs have been fixed. (Now already using Kali Rolling Kernel 4.18.0, GNOME 3.30.1)

Comment: You're welcome. I used info known to work as of today on gdm3, that is why I just thought why not. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score -2):

My laptops runs *Kali Linux* with the *Gnome* DE.  Here's how I just changed the *lockscreen* & *login* screen backgrounds:

1. open terminal, type in `su root` then your password,
2. type in, `cd /usr/share/images/desktop-base` then press *enter*.
3. type `ls` and find the *png* file that says *kali wallpaper* that fits your screen size and type in `mv filename.png filename.png.bak` to make a backup file.
4. Then type `ls` to see changed results then put your desired image in that folder, then label it with the same name as original ending with *.png* ext.
5. then lock the screen, and see results.